# NSImageView resized with image size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsscrollview, nsimageview

I'm new to Obj-C/Cocoa programming and facing to a problem about NSImageView.

My goal is to create an app which allow the user to put an image on it with drag&drop.

The problem is the following : when we're dropping an image larger than the window, it resizes the window to the image size, **I don't want that** !
I put my NSImageView into a NSScrollView so only a certain part of the image **MUST** be showed and the user will move sliders to view the entire one (or simply resize the window), that's what I want..

Here is my XIB hierarchy (concerned part) :

- View

  - NSScrollView

    - View

      - NSImageView

In the code of my NSImageView, I have (about that problem) :

```
[self setImageScaling:NSScaleProportionally];
[self setImage:newImage];
```

*NOTE*: The sliders seem to move the view and not the image

*NOTE2*: I can't resize the window to a lower size than the image

Comment: What do you mean by "the sliders seem to move the view and not the image"?

Comment: I mean when I'm scrolling to top/bottom, we can see the view is moving, and returns to the default position automatically.

Comment: Ok. I get what your problem is. What you're describing sounds to me like the view inside your NSScrollView is not big enough. Because `clip subviews` is probably not enabled, you can still see the NSImageView outside of its bounds. And the reason, why you can scroll and it returns to its original position is a feature called bouncing, which is part of the NSScrollView. Could you please debug your application and check the sizes of `yournsimageview` and `yourscrollview.view`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a horrible aversion to nib files and prefer to do things programmatically whenever possible so I'm not much help with that... but here's a little listing from a little NSScrollview test app I recently coded up that does something similar. The only non-self-contained thing mentioned in this code chunk is the `window` name, which refers to an `NSWindow *` for a window that was already created. And `self` here just refers to a controller object.

```
NSImage * myImage       = [NSImage imageNamed:@"myfilename.png"];
NSRect imageRect        = NSMakeRect(0.0,0.0,myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height);


self.myImageView        = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
self.myImageView.bounds = imageRect;
self.myImageView.image  = myImage;

self.myScrollView       = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[window.contentView frame]];
self.myScrollView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
self.myScrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;
self.myScrollView.documentView = self.myImageView;
self.myScrollView.borderType = NSNoBorder;
self.myScrollView.scrollerStyle = NSScrollerStyleOverlay;

window.contentView      = self.myScrollView;
```

I know that's perhaps not the solution you were looking for but maybe it helps you debug? In particular, I didn't do anything funny with my `NSImageView` besides give it a frame, a bounds rectangle, and an `NSImage *`, so I don't think you need to worry about the scaling parameter per se -- in fact, if you want the image to be full-sized and to scroll around it, you want your `NSImageView`'s frame to be the same size as the image so that it doesn't HAVE to scale at all. Maybe that's your problem -- the frame is too small? It is OK for the NSImageView frame to be bigger than the window -- that's what lets you scroll around it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really would like to use Interface Builder for that task ! And with the actual code I have, I'm not sure I can use your solution..

Comment: Fair enough about Interface Builder, but hopefully you realize that this is pretty much the minimum possible code necessary to create an NSScrollView that does what you want. And it's the same thing that Interface Builder is doing behind the scenes -- all the settings and selections you make in Interface Builder are essentially just telling it to execute code like this when your app starts up. So if you can't find a way to make something like this work with your code, there might be something more fundamental wrong with your code.

Comment: The other reason why I think it might be better for you to try the code here (besides the fact that I don't know the answer off the top of my head for Interface Builder) is that IB has a million little checkboxes and settings buried in various panes, and if you don't have them all checked and unchecked and selected just right, things might not work as expected. Whereas if someone gives you code that is known to work, and you paste it in, it should still work -- you don't have to worry that there's a checkbox somewhere you missed that is breaking your app.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like your views don't have the proper sizes. Because of bouncing and because your views don't clip their subviews, you can still scroll a bit, but it returns to its original position.

1. Check if the NSImageView is big enough to display your full image. (Check frame or bounds for width and height)

   If it is not big enough do this (inside the method, where you set the new image):

   `self.myImageView.frame = NSMakeRect(0.0,0.0, self.myImageView.image.size.width, self.myImageView.image.size.height);`
2. Adjust the size of your scroll views view accordingly.

   `self.myScrollView.view.frame = self.myImageView.frame;`

Now your scrollable area should be big enough to cover the full image.

*If this works for you, give Matt some credit as well, by up-voting his answer, since his answer does essentially the same thing - only code based, instead of initialising everything using a nib file - and the code I used is very similar to what he had already posted.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, your `myScrollView.view` (forgot to use the "inner" view) works ! And don't worry, he's starting at StackOverflow, I'll give +1 to each his answer here because that's good answers too :) !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the "image view" inside of the custom view (edges to its superview).
The image view's constraints to the equal edges, except the bottom constraint, which to the "Less Than or Equal" relation to its superview.

[image]